# Pyplot shows different colors in legend but plots in same color

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot nstrats different pareto fronts using Pyplot, but whatever I seem to try, each front comes out in the same color. I've tried doing this both with and without the colors array below, as I read that Python automatically cycles through colors. Maybe something is wrong with how I'm using the plot/scatter function in a loop? My code and a link to the output plot is below. Especially note that the legend shows the correct colors for my fronts, but all of the output is one color. I've validated that the output are from multiple strategies. Thank you for your help!

```
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
for i in range(nstrats):
    plt.scatter(NPV[i], dev[i], color=colors[i], label = 'Strategy ' +         str(i+1))
plt.xlabel("NPV of Harvest Strategy")
plt.ylabel("Standard Dev of Yearly Harvest")
plt.title("Pareto Front for Each Strategy")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

What my program outputs:

[image: output image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Perhaps the issue is in your data?

Comment: gah! You're actually right! Is there a way I can mark your comment as helpful or mark this question as obsolete? Fairly novice at stackoverflow. Thank you so much!

Comment: maybe you could close the question? Not sure if you can do that yourself or not. I'll vote to close it as not-reproducible

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the argument color to c.

```
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
for i in range(nstrats):
    plt.scatter(NPV[i], dev[i], c=colors[i], label = 'Strategy ' + str(i+1))
plt.xlabel("NPV of Harvest Strategy")
plt.ylabel("Standard Dev of Yearly Harvest")
plt.title("Pareto Front for Each Strategy")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

NOTE: Keep the value of *(nstart <= 3*). Otherwise, it will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I got the same output using c=colors[i] as suggested. Are you saying that for nstrats >= 3 this code will not perform as expected? Can you elaborate? Thanks again.

Comment: If you keep the value of *nstarts > 3*, then the loop will run for more that 4 times and the value of *i* will  3 at some point. This will raise list index out of bound exception because of color[i].

Comment: ah yes. nstrats won't be more than 5, i'll add a few more colors. regardless, everything is showing up as blue (or generally, i guess the last color in the list) :(. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This happens because everything is plotted by the same single plot command.

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [1, 100, 2, 200, 3, 300, 4, 400, 5, 500]
data = np.reshape(data, (5, 2))

column = 0
chunks = dict()
chunks[0] = data[data[:, column] < 300]
chunks[1] = data[data[:, column] >= 300]

for i in chunks:
    plt.plot(chunks[i][:, 0], chunks[i][:, 1], "x", label="Chunk %i" % i)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The data should be splitted into chunks based on the y value. But a mistake occurred, instead of 1 for column y 0 was entered for column x. Because of this mistake chunk 0 is a complete copy of data and chunk 1 is empty. Therefore everything is plotted by the first plot command in the same color. The second command only adds the label with a different color to the legend since there is no data to plot in chunk 1.